# XSL:IF with orcondition implementation in xslt1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below template as shown..

```
<xsl:for-each select="/abc/def">
    <xsl:if test=".Id='xxx' and ./Role='yyy' "> 
            <xsl:value-of select=" 'true'"/>
        </xsl:if>
```

Now I want to put an or condition in an xsl:if condition such that let say condition 1 is true then also result should be true or if condition 2 is true then also the result is true , now please advise how to put the or condition
I have come up with this solution please advise is it correct ....

```
<xsl:if test=".Id='xxx' and ./Role='yyy'  or  test=".Id='ttt' and ./Role='ccc' ">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime I'm not sure about priorities I use brackets, so e.g.  test="(Id='xxx' and Role='yyy') or (Id='ttt' and Role='ccc')".
Btw, there is only one "test" attribute in "if", you don't need to repeat it for second condition.

Comment: S Thanks a lot as you have advised don't need to repeat for second condition then how would I write my other condition please advise

Comment: @TuntunDfdhflflfff Jirka already showed you in his answer. Look closer.